# ReferenceError: value is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Node.js and have problem with a function. This function works fine if i put him in the same file. But if i call it from another file, it does not work. When i use debugger, i see that I can call the function but when i use the parameter, it keeps saying ReferenceError: value is not defined.

```
documentDBConfig.getById = function (feedId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.queryDocuments(
            feedCollectionUrl,               
            'SELECT * FROM feeds r where r.id =' + feedId.toString()
        ).toArray((err, results) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                if (typeof results[0] !== 'undefined' && results[0] !== null) {
                    documentDBConfig.feedsArray = results;
                }
                console.log();
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = documentDBConfig;
```

Just because it keeps saying that, i used a property of a same object too `documentDBConfig.feedsId`. But it keeps still saying `ReferenceError: value is not defined`. In the debugger it sees the value and assign to `documentDBConfig.feedsId` without a problem but does not pass to another file. And without the value works this function fine. How can i fix that?

```
documentDBConfig.feedsId = req.params.id;
console.log(documentDBConfig.feedsId);
    documentDBConfig.getById(documentDBConfig.feedsId)
        .then(() => res.json(documentDBConfig.feedsArray));
```

Edit: I found that the problem is caused by the query `'SELECT * FROM feeds r where r.id =' + feedId.toString()` If i write it hardcoded forexample `'SELECT * FROM rss r where r.id = "5"'` It works fine. I know documentdb accepts only strings for an id value, therefore i used toString() method. Is there any another solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by the changing the query.

```
 'SELECT * FROM rss r where r.id =' + '"' + documentDBConfig.feedsId + '"'
```

It works fine now.